# Oracle : calculate duration between two dates in specific format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I would like to calculate the differnce between two dates (timestamp) but 
in a specific format like DDd HH24:MI:SS.FF

As an example : 2d 10:25:30.350

There many examples on the net but most of them separate the days, hours, minutes.. in differents columns and not getting all of them in one column

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/5169)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
WITH times ( start_time, end_time ) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2015-01-03 10:25:30.350' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 09:00:00.000607' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-03-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2016-03-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2016-01-11 00:00:00' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_CHAR( start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6' ) AS start_time,
       TO_CHAR( end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6' ) AS end_time,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( end_time - start_time, '^[+-]0*(\d+) 0?(\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\d*?)0*$', '\1d \2' ) AS time_difference
FROM   times
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/5169/0)**:

```
|                 START_TIME |                   END_TIME |   TIME_DIFFERENCE |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|-------------------|
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2015-01-03 10:25:30.350000 |   2d 10:25:30.350 |
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2015-01-01 09:00:00.000607 | 0d 9:00:00.000607 |
| 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000000 |  366d 0:00:00.000 |
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2016-01-11 00:00:00.000000 |  375d 0:00:00.000 |
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. just one comment the milliseconds in the second line (0d 9:00:00.000607) are 6 digits while the others are 3 digits. So is there a solution to make the format the same for all of them? Like Days=3 digits, hours, minutes and seconds=2 digits, milliseconds=5 digits. Example: for the first line in your example the input will be 00210253035000 (DDDHHMMSSFFFFF)  .Thanks again

Comment: Or [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/8865/0) - both of those will truncate (not round) the fractional seconds to 5 d.p. (and if there are more than 999 days will display extra digits at the start - but will always display at least 3 days digits)

Comment: It works fine. For the second one, how we can remove the separator before the milliseconds ? 002102530.35000 to 00210253035000. Thanks

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE( end_time - start_time, '^[+-]0*(\d{3,}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{5})\d*$', '\1\2\3\4\5' )`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you will never have more than 365 days, you can use a valid date and only print the numbers.  I'm thinking of something like this:

```
select (case when ts1 - ts2 < 1
             then '000d ' || to_char(date '2000-01-01' + (t1 - t2), 'HH24:MI:SS')
             else to_char(date '2000-01-01' + (t1 - t2) - 1, 'DDDd HH24:MI:SS')
        end)
```

This does zero-pad the day component.  It is easy enough to remove the leading zeros if that is desired.

Comment: This one works. But I get "date format not recognized" when I try to get the milliseconds like 'DDDd HH24:MI:SS.FF3' . So how can I get the milliseconds with this solution ?

Comment: @kkung . . . I would expect `'FF3'` to work.  Perhaps, though, the value needs to be a `timestamp`.